# C++ Difference between A foo() and A::foo()

Tags: c++, oop, methods

When I run the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
  
class A
{
    public:
    virtual void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Foo\n";
    }
};

class B : A
{
    public:
    virtual void foo() override
    {
        A foo();
        std::cout << "Bar\n";
    }
};


int main()
{
    B b;
    b.foo();
}
```

I get the following result: `Bar`.

I understand that to get:

```
Foo
Bar
```

I would need to replace `A foo();` with `A::foo();`.
But I'm having trouble understanding what `A foo();` is, as it seems that that statement (or declaration?) is skipped.

Note: I'm using g++ 7.4 on a x86 machine.
Thanks!

Comment: `A foo();` -- I'll give you a small test -- declare a function called `foo` that takes no arguments and returns an `A` object.  Does that answer look like this declaration?

Comment: So is it a prototype? Can you define prototypes inside of a method?

Comment: don't confuse definitions and declarations. `A foo();` is a declaration, `A foo() { return {};}` is a definition

Comment: Yes, I understand that... But what does it mean that I can have a declaration inside of a definition. Why? What am I declaring, a function that is only visible inside of a method?

Comment: You can declare, but not define, a function inside a function definition. It means the same as declaring it "globally", but the name is limited to the function's scope.

Comment: There are cases where you need a declaration of something that will only be defined at a later point. Actually I am not sure if this example is legal, but consider this: https://godbolt.org/z/MT6TWG7qj

Comment: Thanks! That was my question.

Comment: @Matinho *Can you define prototypes inside of a method?* -- You could declare a function inside a method.  As a matter of fact, this has been the case for C++ since the beginning, and it takes it from the `C` language.

Answer (score 2):

`A foo();` declares a function that has no arguments, returns an `A` and is called `foo`.

`A::foo();` is something entirely different. It calls the method `A::foo`.

Comment: @Matinho No, you can't. But you can define lambdas inside other functions.

Comment: @digito_evo classes can be defined inside functions (and lambdas are a special case of that). I think you posted the comment in the wrong place ;)

Comment: The OP's comment has been deleted. And yes, lambdas are function objects as far as I know. Pre-C++11, people used to define structs containing a function that acted like a lambda.

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing a phenomenon commonly referred to as [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). It usually manifests when trying to initialise a variable:

```
Type variable1;
Type variable2(value);
Type function1();
Type function2(Type);
```

It is easy to be misled into thinking that `Type x();` and `Type y(1);` should roughly do a similar thing, but the former declares a function while the latter declares and defines a local variable.

In your case in the example, `foo` is not the member function `A::foo` but a local declaration of a function that would shadow the member function you are keen on calling.

The fact that this is seldom useful in function scopes is even more vexing, but that's just how the C++ parser works. Declaration syntax does not distinguish between global and local scope.